# Finding average in in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `DEPARTMENT_ID` decimal(6,0) NOT NULL,
  `DEPARTMENT_NAME` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `MANAGER_ID` decimal(8,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION_ID` decimal(6,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DEPARTMENT_ID`),
  KEY `LOCATION_ID` (`LOCATION_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_departments_locations` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCATION_ID`) REFERENCES `locations` (`LOCATION_ID`)


CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `EMPLOYEE_ID` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `PHONE_NUMBER` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `HIRE_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_ID` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `SALARY` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMISSION_PCT` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MANAGER_ID` decimal(8,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPARTMENT_ID` decimal(6,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EMPLOYEE_ID`),
  KEY `DEPARTMENT_ID` (`DEPARTMENT_ID`),
  KEY `MANAGER_ID` (`MANAGER_ID`),
  KEY `JOB_ID` (`JOB_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employees_departments` FOREIGN KEY (`DEPARTMENT_ID`) REFERENCES `departments` (`DEPARTMENT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employees_employees` FOREIGN KEY (`MANAGER_ID`) REFERENCES `employees` (`EMPLOYEE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employees_jobs` FOREIGN KEY (`JOB_ID`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`JOB_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So, in one query how do i *find all departments whose employees have average salary greater or equal to $10,000*. Names should be displayed

So far i have tried

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID AS depts, SALARAY 
FROM bliu.employees 
WHERE salary >= 10000 
JOIN departments 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = depts
```

it didnt wont work

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?  Not the same thing. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've got a feeling we probably shouldn't be doing your homework

Comment: It its a Mysql, i tried joining them, but it didnt work

Comment: Please post your effort so far and maybe someone will guide you the rest of the way.

Comment: SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID AS depts, SALARAY FROM bliu.employees WHERE salary >= 10000 JOIN departments WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = depts

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic SQL and I'm guessing that the point of the exercise is to use the `GROUP BY ... HAVING` syntax.

```
SELECT 
  D.DEPARTMENT_NAME,                 -- what column to show
  AVG(E.SALARY) AS AverageSalary     -- strictly not needed, but nice to show
FROM DEPARTMENTS AS D                -- from what table, using an alias (D)
JOIN EMPLOYEES AS E                  -- join the emp table (E) to get salaries
ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID -- join on this condition (dept_id equality)
GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_ID             -- group the data by department
HAVING AVG(E.SALARY) >= 10000        -- and filter the groups
                                     -- for avg(salary) >= 10000
```

Comment: @RADAR Thanks. I'm guessing it's a homework or exercise type question so I felt like adding some explanation would be good instead of just dumping the query :)